# Where should I copy-paste-install software to?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure, intellij

I'm installing IntelliJ, and the readme tells me to choose an installation folder. Where is a good, standard place to put installed programs?

Comment: If you are the only user of it, just slap it in `/home`. If not, `/opt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are the only user of it, just slap it in `/home`. If not, `/opt/intellij`.

Avoid `/usr`, which should only be used by distro-managed software. Many source installers use `/usr/local` by default, but the advantage of `/opt/intellij` is that you can wipe the entire directory if you no longer have a use for it. Putting it under `/usr/local`, the stuff would get distributed all over the place, adding the need to track where those are installed; there's tools for that, but don't  bother. Any decent installer should create all directory structures for your installation to work, wherever you choose to install to.

Comment: /home/myusername is on an NFS drive, so that's a no go. I'm the only user of the machine - so /opt, you say?

Answer (score 1):

*(adapted from my answer to [an earlier, similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7882) about packages installed from source)*

If you start having many programs installed outside your distribution, you'll start running into package management issues: what version of foo have I installed? What files belong to foo, so that I can remove it (if you have foo mixed with other packages)? I'm tired of adding yet another directory to my `PATH` (if you have foo in a directory of its own). So I recommend using some form of package management.

[Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) is a poor-man's package manager. The principle is to store each package in its own directory but maintain symlinks in standard directories.

- Install under `/usr/local/stow/PACKAGE-VERSION` (or `~/usr/stow/PACKAGE-VERSION` or wherever). (`PACKAGE` and `VERSION` represent the name and version of the package. These names are for your convenience only.)
- If you picked a directory other than `/usr/local/stow`, add `~/usr/bin` (or wherever) to your `PATH`.
- Run `stow PACKAGE-VERSION` from the `/usr/local/stow` (or …) directory. This creates symbolic links in the “normal” directories, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/foo-command -> ../../stow/foo-4.2/bin/foo-command`.
- If you ever want to uninstall this program, just run `stow -D PACKAGE-VERSION` to remove the symbolic links, and delete `/usr/local/stow/PACKAGE-VERSION`.

There is also [xstow](http://xstow.sourceforge.net/) which is a similar, but more powerful programs (one of its benefits is that it can deal with conflicts).