# Package managers for local installations under home directory

Tags: software-installation, apt, administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-Root Package Managers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/non-root-package-managers)

I work extensively on a remote system where I do not have admin rights. However, I am allowed to install my own binaries and programs under my home directory where I have about 10 GB of space. Unfortunately doing this manually for many packages is becoming increasingly tedious.

I am wondering if I could use a package manager like [`apt`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt) to install/update/remove local installations. Is this feasible? Are package managers designed to support this usage? What are the steps I need to take to install `apt` as my *local* package manager?

Comment: see also [best way to set up separate linux environment in ~](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7882/best-way-to-set-up-separate-linux-environment-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory) is relatively similar to your problem. From the answers, it seems that neither `dpkg` nor `apt` have this capability. The answers suggest the usage of `debootstrap` and `fakeroot` but no clear answer was provided on this. An other suggestion is to compile from source, but this is no package manager.